# Get a portion of a line from a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, hp-ux

I have a file named , temp.lst whose contents are something like this :

```
1,13d0
< /hello/ux/PH/src/DEMO/dir/web/HelloWorld.java
< /hello/ux/PH/src/USOURCES/java/frame/contain/ProcessResult.js
< /hello/ux/PH/src/DEMO/dir/web/Hello.java
< /hello/ux/PH/src/USOURCES/dir/web/World.java
< /hello/ux/PH/src/USOURCES/dir/web/Hey.java
```

I need only those lines that are having the word "USOURCES" and discard everything that is before "USOURCES". This needs to be dumped into another file , say final.lst.

So, the final.lst would be :

```
USOURCES/java/frame/contain/ProcessResult.js
USOURCES/dir/web/World.java
USOURCES/dir/web/Hey.java
```

I tried using cut command , but that is not very generic. Please help as i am new to unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n 's@.*/USOURCES@USOURCES@p' temp.lst
```

`-n` says do not print unless explicitly told to by `p` at the end.  The rest is simply deleting from lines that match and printing them.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

You can use [`grep` option `-o`](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep%20-o) and a [glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob?action=show&redirect=globbing) for that.

```
grep -o 'USOURCES.*' /tmp/so.txt
```

Output:

> ```
> USOURCES/java/frame/contain/ProcessResult.js
> USOURCES/dir/web/World.java
> USOURCES/dir/web/Hey.java
> ```

#### Explaination

> **-o, --only-matching**
>
> ```
>    Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line, 
>    with each such part on a separate output line.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'USOURCES' 'NF>1{print FS $2}' temp.lst > final.lst
```